# SwiftUI NavigationLink Item foregroundColor not working

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Im trying to use SwiftUI List & NavigationLink with custom font/colors/view
Nothing is working I tried setting the .foregroundColor and using other View customized yet i cant change the color of the text, i only want to have a black text color nothing fancy

```
    struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List{
            Section(header: Text("North America")){
                NavigationLink(destination: CASettingsView() ) {
                    SettingItemView(value: "USA")
                }.foregroundColor(.red)
                NavigationLink(
                   destination: Text("Destination"),
                   label: {
                       Text("Click Here!")
                           .foregroundColor(.black)
                   }
                )
            }
        }
        
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}

struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CASettingsView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use .tint or .accentColor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your NavigationLinks are greyed out because they aren’t embedded in a NavigationView. Wrap your whole list in NavigationView { }

Comment: Thank you this seems to have solve it but what I want to use it without a NavigationView ?

Comment: You can’t use NavigationLink without a NavigationView. NavigationView is what provides the mechanism and UI for actually navigating.